# NullPointerException xml layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying create a LinearLayout with ScrollView. Inside this ScrollView I need some ListView. When I created does throws an exception, NullPointerException I can't understand why does problem.

I'm trying this.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Header-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_carrinho"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNomeCliente"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/action_bar"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Nome do cliente:"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Nucleo-->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="#ffe3b3"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/action_bar"
                    android:text="Quant."/>

                <TextView
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Produtos Pronta Entrega"
                    android:textColor="@color/action_bar"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/action_bar"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="Excluir"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lvProntaEntrega"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="#a84be1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Total:"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTotalProntaEntrega"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="R$ 300,00:"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="#ffe3b3"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/action_bar"
                    android:text="Quant."/>

                <TextView
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Produtos Entrega Futura"
                    android:textColor="@color/action_bar"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/action_bar"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="Excluir"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lvEntregaFutura"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="#a84be1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Total:"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTotalEntregaFutura"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="R$ 10,00:"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Previsão de entrega"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@color/action_bar">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Valor Total da Compra:"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvValorTotalCompra"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="R$ 500,00:"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Forma de Pagamento"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinFormaPagto"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </Spinner>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/icone_desconto"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Finalizar"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:background="#FF8C00"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Limpar"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:background="#FF8C00"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawShadow(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:74)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:592)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1689)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15022)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15022)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:587)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:334)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:688)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:677)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:677)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:815)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:646)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:584)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a ListView inside of a ScrollView. [From the dcos](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) *"You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, "*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set scrollview height to wrap_content and also of its Child Linear layout also,it may not draw the layout due to nested match_parent dependency.so it will look like

```
   ......
   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    ......
```